# Paypal Adaptive Chained Payment - Set Primary Receiver Payment Type

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained

I'm currently using the Adaptive Payments on my website. When a buyer purchases a product from one of my merchants, I get my commission and then the seller gets the rest of the profit.

The issue is that the payment that the seller receives is of payment type SERVICES, instead of GOODS. When this happens, my sellers lose seller protection.

I have tried setting the paymentType property of the Reciever class but no luck, the transaction still comes to my seller as paymentType SERVICES.

Please advise. Can I set the Receiver paymentType = GOODS is it possible?

Thanks!

```
        ReceiverList receiverList = new ReceiverList();

        decimal merchantFee = new decimal(0.04);
        decimal baseCommission = (orderAmount * merchantFee);
        double finalCommission = Convert.ToDouble(baseCommission);
        finalCommission = GlobalHelper.RoundUp(finalCommission, 2);

        receiverList.receiver = new List<Receiver>();

        Receiver primaryReceiver = new Receiver();
        primaryReceiver.amount = orderAmount;
        primaryReceiver.email = primaryRecieverEmail;
        primaryReceiver.primary = true;
        primaryReceiver.paymentType = "GOODS";
        receiverList.receiver.Add(primaryReceiver);

        Receiver secondaryReceiver = new Receiver();
        secondaryReceiver.amount = Convert.ToDecimal(finalCommission);
        secondaryReceiver.email = secondaryRecieverEmail;
        secondaryReceiver.primary = false;
        receiverList.receiver.Add(secondaryReceiver);

        RequestEnvelope requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_US");
        string actionType = "PAY";
        string returnUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PaypalReturnUrl"];
        string cancelUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PaypalCancelUrl"];
        string currencyCode = "USD";
        PayRequest payRequest = new PayRequest(requestEnvelope, actionType, cancelUrl, currencyCode, receiverList, returnUrl);
        payRequest.ipnNotificationUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PaypalNotifyUrl"];
        payRequest.trackingId = (orderId).ToString();
        payRequest.memo = String.Format("{0} {1}","Payment for",title);

        Dictionary<string, string> sdkConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        sdkConfig.Add("mode", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_MODE"]);
        sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiUsername", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_USERNAME"]);
        sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiPassword", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_PASSWORD"]);
        sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiSignature", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_SIGNATURE"]);
        sdkConfig.Add("account1.applicationId", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APPLICATION-ID"]);

        AdaptivePaymentsService adaptivePaymentsService = new AdaptivePaymentsService(sdkConfig);
        PayResponse payResponse = adaptivePaymentsService.Pay(payRequest);

        return payResponse;
```

Comment: Need to get a look at the actual API request getting sent to PayPal.  Also, what makes you say that it's the payment type causing the ineligible seller protection as opposed to something else?

Comment: Based on Paypal statement..."We cover physical goods (not digital items or services) that are sold and shipped with proof of delivery from within the United States to buyers around the globe. "

I have updated the post with the entire PayResponse method call. Thanks!

Comment: What you provided isn't the raw request/response.  It's the code used to generate it.  You should have a raw XML request/response somewhere.  That's what I'd like to see.  Also, are you indeed shipping physical product or are you trying to get covered for digital goods?  PayPal simply will not cover digital goods.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll get you the raw req/res, I guess I can use Fiddler to see that?. My sellers ship physical product, no digital goods.

Comment: Ok, well, the default for PayPal is to consider the order is for physical goods, so as long as you're sending a shipping address with the payment request you should be covered.  I'm not seeing that in your code, though..??  With Adaptive Payments you would need to make an additional call to SetPaymentOptions in order to add shipping details.

Comment: Ok that makes sense...and yes I am not making a call to SetPaymentOptions. I think I'll go ahead, do that and then see what happens on the seller's end. Thanks buddy!